# Toggle button is not on

Tags: android

I found a code for turning on Mobile Data programmatically, but from some reason my toggle button is not on when I start application (I turned on Mobile Data before - only for checking if button is working properly). I would like to mention that button is working fine if Mobile Data is not turned on before starting application.

This code is for toggle button:

```
gprs.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

     @Override
     public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
         try {
             turnData(isChecked);  //Klasa za ukljucivanje gprsa
         } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
});
```

And Class:

```
void turnData(boolean ON) throws Exception {

Log.i("version:", "Found Gingerbread+");
       final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

       final Class conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
       final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
       iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
       final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
       final Class iConnectivityManagerClass =  Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
       final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
       setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
       setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, ON);
}
```

EDIT: For WiFi is very easy, but for Mobile Data I dont know why toggle is not on

```
wifiManager = (WifiManager)this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifi.setChecked(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled());

        wifi.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {


            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(isChecked);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Can't you just add `toggleButton.setChecked()` in the `onCreate()` method of the Activity where you want it to be checked at the first place?

Comment: If I make it gprs.setChecked() it says that it needs to be setChecked(boolean)...If I do it like that I have two options; to call isInternetPresent or false. I tried both, but nothing changes...

Comment: Oh, so you want it checked if there's internet connection and unchecked if not - then yes, you'd better check that in the `onCreate()` just to be sure.

Comment: That's the problem, I dont know how to do it...

Comment: Ok, I'll paste some pseudo code as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Toggle button, depending from the presentce of Internet connection:

The function below can be re-used to check if there's anetwork connection:

```
public boolean connectivityCheck(){
    CheckConnectivity check = new CheckConnectivity();
    check = new CheckConnectivity();
    return check.checkNow(this.getApplicationContext());
}
```

*This is the **CheckConnectivity.class** also:*

```
package com.yourPackageName;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class CheckConnectivity {

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
    NetworkInfo wifiInfo, mobileinfo;

    public Boolean checkNow(Context con){

        try{

            connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) con.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            wifiInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            mobileinfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

            if(wifiInfo.isConnected() || mobileinfo.isConnected()){
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("CheckConnectivity Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

In the `onCreate()` method put:

```
if(connectivityCheck()){
  //There's an internet connection
  toggleButton.setChecked(true);
}
else{
  toggleButton.setChecked(false);
}
```

Cheers :-)

Comment: Are you sure it's not ConnectivityManager?

Comment: Oh yes, i'm really sorry, i forgot that I use it in a separate class :-D However I updated the answer - don't forget to include the appropriate permissions, like `NETWORK_STATE` etc.

Comment: Welcome +1 for the question :)